# yii2-user dektrium module registration email was not received

Tags: php, yii2

I have a trouble.
I install a yii2-user module by folowing link https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/tree/0.9.9
When I trying to register I got a success message, but I not receiving confirmation email.
I used OpenServer

**config/web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'mailer' => [
                'sender'                => ['name@gmail.com' => 'Vlad'], // or ['no-reply@myhost.com' => 'Sender name']
                'welcomeSubject'        => 'Welcome subject',
                'confirmationSubject'   => 'Confirmation subject',
                'reconfirmationSubject' => 'Email change subject',
                'recoverySubject'       => 'Recovery subject',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'QqvFfvH3g3PwMMu_bRRHB4Qz0uPJwiB-',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        // 'user' => [
        //     'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        //     'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        // ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
            'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // 'transport' => [
            //     'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            //     'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            //     'username' => 'name@gmail.com',
            //     'password' => 'mypassword',
            //     'port' => '587',
            //     'encryption' => 'tls',
            // ],
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            // 'useFileTransport' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Comment: you need to configure your `swiftmailer` settings

Answer (score 1):

Untill your environment is in dev mode, you will never receive the emails.
You have 3 differents way for read the emails:

1. the dev bar in bottom, if there is not any redirect after send email, you can open and find it there
2. in the server, looking for runtime/mail/ folder and there will be the sended emails
3. deploy enviroment from developer to production

Answer (score 0):

The mailer component should be at the same level as model component. 
You can configure it as follows:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@app/mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io', // your host, here using fake email server (https://mailtrap.io/). You can use gmail: 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com'
            'username' => 'your host username',
            'password' => 'your host password',
            'port' => '2525',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```